# can I use columns with object type in xgboost?

Tags: machine-learning, dask, xgboost, dask-distributed, dask-dataframe

I want to develop Xgboost model on `Dask`. I import parquet files and all columns have `object` type. Do I need to convert column's type from `object` to `numeric`? If do, what is most convenient way to do this? should I use `dask.dataframe.to_numeric` function?

Comment: Did you try any of these things? What happened when you did? What kind of objects are in your dataframe?

Comment: I have 1500 features and 300000 observations. Only 3 features are categorical and they are encoded using one-hot encoder. All other features should be numeric. I try to change type to numeric with following code: `train[vars] = dd.to_numeric(train[vars])` (where `vars` are vector of column's names) but there was following error: `TypeError: arg must be a list, tuple, dask.array.Array, or dask.dataframe.Series`.

Comment: seems like it'd be easy enough to hard code a dataset with ~7 columns and 5 rows to demonstrate this issue